# M4A audio files not recognized by Samsung Recorder app

Tags: samsung, audio, ffmpeg, samsung-voice-recorder

I need to convert my M4A audio files to M4A but with a 3GP4 codec (it seems Samsung audio recording app only recognizes those with a 3GP4 codec).

How can I do that with ffmpeg or any other program?

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -brand "3gp4" output.m4a
```

This did change the major brand to 3gp4, but the Samsung Recorder app still doesn't recognize the audio file.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Just for clarity, could you explain why you want the app to recognize the audio file, or what you're *really* trying to achieve? While the community might be able to find the solution for the current issue, I have a feeling that this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919) where X is "make the audio file be recognized by Samsung Recorder (for...?)", and Y is "converting the audio file".

Comment: Thank you. I need the files to appear in Samsung Recorder, that's what I meant by "they are not recognized", i.e. they don't appear in the app.